# Yup argument not assignable to parameter of type ObjectShape

Tags: typescript, validation, yup

So I'm trying to create yup validation with DTOs.

I get two errors:

1. Yup argument is not assignable to parameter of type ObjectShape
2. Property id is not assignable to index signature. Type number is not assignable to type 'Anyschema'

I have no clue whats wrong.If I remove CargoTypeDetailDto everything works perfect..

If the problems get fixed I have another question. The id is set by backend and does not need to be validated. Is there any other way to go about it other than yup.number().notRequired() ?

Here is the code:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { CargoTypeDetailDto } from '../../../../../api/planning/open-api/models/CargoTypeDetailDto'

export const cargoTypeDetailDtoSchema = yup.object(<CargoTypeDetailDto>).shape({
  id: yup.number().notRequired(),
  code: yup
    .string()
    .min(1, 'Code can not be below 1')
    .max(10, 'Code can not be above 10')
    .required('Code is required'),
  description: yup
    .string()
    .min(1, 'Description can not be below 1')
    .max(255, 'Description can not be above 255')
    .required('Description is required'),
  priceCode: yup.object().shape({
    code: yup.string().required('Article code is required'),
    name: yup.string().required('Article description is required'),
  }),
  cargoTypeEuCode: yup.object().shape({
    code: yup.string().required('EU code is required'),
    description: yup.string().required('EU description is required'),
  }),
})
```

The DTO:

```
import type { CargoTypeEuCodeDto } from './CargoTypeEuCodeDto';
import type { PriceCodeDto } from './PriceCodeDto';

export type CargoTypeDetailDto = {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    description: string;
    priceCode: PriceCodeDto;
    cargoTypeEuCode: CargoTypeEuCodeDto;
};
```